# F# type inference with Array.sum

Tags: f#, type-inference

Why do I have to tell F# whether I am using a int or float in this line
`let total counts = Array.sum counts` to `let total (counts:int[]) = Array.sum counts` ?

Coming from sml I am finding F# type inference a bit too restrictive.

P.S. I don't know much about the landscape of functional languages but would be interested if someone could enlighten me which F-languages are used out in the wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer but you have the option of creating an inline function which will be more generic:

```
let inline total counts = Array.sum counts
```

The type of this automatically gets inferred with the necessary statically resolved type parameters:

```
> val inline total:
  counts:  ^a[] ->  ^a
    when  ^a: (static member (+) :  ^a *  ^a ->  ^a) and
          ^a: (static member get_Zero: ->  ^a)
```

Usage:

```
total [|1; 2; 3|] // 6
total [|1.; 2.; 3.|] // 6.0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this is much less restrictive. After skimming the docs it seems inline should be used with care. "Inline functions are functions that are integrated directly into the calling code." This has the potential to "leak" code between modules, not reusing the library compiled code. Is a good practice to use inline functions internally only?

Comment: @Alex_ `inline` in F# doesn't mean what it means in most other contexts.  It's a misnomer, really.  What is the source of your quote?

Comment: @Alex_ It can definitely be abused and make code overly complicated and compilation very slow. But for certain very generic library-style functions it can be useful. Several F# core library functions are marked as inline for this reason.

Comment: @phoog MSDN docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/inline-functions

Comment: Also see my follow up question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71642273/should-i-enforce-a-type-with-f-units-of-measure-style-vs-generality

Comment: @Alex_ thanks.  I suspect that this definition is slightly misleading in the F# context, notwithstanding its appearance in the F# docs.  Inlining traditionally means literally integrating the function code into the calling function, and I am fairly certain that the F# compiler does not do that: in F# an `inline` function can be arbitrarily long and the keyword is relevant to the programmer because of type inference, not performance.  Try decompiling an F# program that uses inline functions and you'll see that they are normal IL calls.

Comment: @phoog I believe the `inline` keyword can indeed inline the function as you describe, but only under certain conditions (unknown to me). It can definitely affect performance. E.g. the pipe forward operator `|>` is simply an inline function.

Comment: @phoog This can be seen [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfYBTALgAgJYDti5QzQHs0BDYDAY2IFcc0IMBeDAQQCcOyBPAOgi0AttToMIAWABQ01JiE8AYvSposxHAAoAlC2kYDRUhQwBtRAEYA3BgBMNgMyIAukA==). The `total` function isn't called when compiled/decompiled to C#. Even `Array.sum` isn't called because it's also inlined.

Comment: But whether the function is inlined in the traditional sense is a matter for the JIT compiler.  The pipe forward operator being defined as `inline` is similarly for type inference; there's no pipe forward function in F#'s .NET libraries (just as there's no `(+)` function -- it's a bit of a fiction maintained by the F# compiler).  The F# compiler _may_ inline a function marked `inline`, as in your example, but there are some cases where it _cannot_ do so (notably `let rec inline ...`).  If you copy the implementation of `Array.sum` into your own module and use it, does the compiler inline that?

Comment: Also the F# compiler has changed a lot since I last investigated this in depth. I suspect that the one I looked at years ago probably would just have called `Array.sum`, but I couldn't swear to it. Certainly if the `inline` function is 100 lines long, it shouldn't be inlined, especially if it's called more than once. I wonder whether there's a way to prevent inlining of `inline` functions explicitly; that is, to restrict its effect to type inference. This would be useful to prevent the leakage you're concerned about.  (This is a corrected version of an earlier comment.)

Answer (score 3):

In F# compilation is single pass and (mostly) strictly feed-forward. I believe this is done to improve compile times but I'm not sure. The result is that in the expression `Array.sum counts` the `sum` function doesn't know what type `counts` is unless you add a type annotation.

You can write the computationally equivalent expression `counts |> Array.sum` and because `counts` appears earlier in the file `sum` is able to resolve the type correctly. This is one of the reasons the [pipeline operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/#pipelines) `|>` is so common in F# code.

(The `rec` and `and` keywords allows the compiler to to refer to things forward in the source file to permit mutually recursive functions and types and `member`s within class definitions are mutually recursive by default but this is the exception.)

Comment: One advantage of one-way inference is that it becomes much easier for the user to understand why a type is being inferred and to fix the resulting errors.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message I get the problem is that you have to constrain it to a type that support the '+' operator.

I assume that both float and int does that but not the default type 'obj' which is the type you get if you don't specify the type of the array.