# Should I enforce a type with F# units of measure? [Style vs generality]

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

This question relates to F# [units of measure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure).

Should I enforce a type for a unit I am using.

For example should I enforce that seconds are always a float?

```
let asSeconds time = float(time)*1.0<second>
```

This seems a tad bit restrictive, since NASA may want to use decimal. On the other hand I don't know how to convert a generic `a'` into a unit `a'<seconds>`. The issue I am facing is that some application level functions do NOT use units, but some library stuff DO use units.

P.S. This is lightly related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71584399/f-type-inference-with-array-sum/71587357?noredirect=1#comment126547559_71587357)

Answer (score 2):

> should I enforce that seconds are always a float?

I don't think you could really enforce this, since units of measure are not inherently tied to a specific numeric type. For example, both of the following would be legal:

```ml
let a = 1<second>     // a : int<second>
let b = 1.0<second>   // b : float<second>
```

> I don't know how to convert a generic `'a` into a unit `'a<seconds>`.

This is an interesting question, but I don't think it's possible to write a generic version of `asSeconds`, because units of measure can only be applied to literals, and literals are never generic in F#. So you can't write `time<second>` or `time * GenericOne<second>`.

Bottom line, when converting from a dimensionless value to a dimensioned value you have to pick a specific numeric type, like `float`. But this doesn't mean that you can force *all* values of that UOM to have that numeric type.

Comment: As an aside units of measure can be applied to values but only of a known type. This is using `LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'measure>`. and similar functions.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. I wasn't aware.